# Project losing references in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2015, system, projects

I am experiencing a wierd one and haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and C#.

I have 3 solutions.  They all include the same common project.  In the first 2 projects all is well and happy.  In the 3rd the common project loses its reference to System.  There have been no changes made to the project.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Steve

[image]

Comment: do all 3 projects share the same `namespace` also for the one that's working vs the one that is not, can you compare the `using statement` in the class header.. can you also be more specific in regards to what the error is or what you mean when you say `loses it's reference to System` show how you are initializing the Class is this a web app or winforms app..

Comment: When you say it loses it you mean? a) It ran home and told it's mum it lost it... b) You open the solution in VSxxx(?) and the reference is lost still there but not found at the location i.e. funny yellowish symbol... c) you have the correct reference, compile and deploy then at run time the reference is lost... d) You open the solution in VSxxx(?) and the reference is completely gone... etc etc etc

Comment: All three solutions are in their own namespaces, as is the common project. When open in the "faulty" solution I have the yellow triangle and in properties all are clear.  The error is a reference can not be found.  The offending solution is a windows service.  The two working ones one is a REST service and one is a WPF desktop application.  I have checked the Framework versions and they are all set to 4.6.1.   Thanks for your help guys

Comment: I've added a screen grab to show what i'm seeing

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now, did you figure out what was causing it?

Comment: Unfortunately i still havent got to the battom of it